# Options of fancyvrb do not work

Tags: line-breaking, fancyvrb

I want to have breaklines with verbatim. For this I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
```

And I set my environment like this:

```
\begin{verbatim}[breaklines=true, breakanywhere=true]
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
\end{verbatim}
```

But my problem is that the option of verbatim is always interpreted as a text:

> [breaklines=true, breakanywhere=true]
> 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I do not understand what I am doing wrong... Can someone help me please?
I also tried with spverbatim, but it does not work...

Best

Comment: These options apply to `\begin{Verbatim}` (with upper case V), not to `\begin{verbatim}`.

Comment: So simple... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The package `fancyvrb` doesn't touch `verbatim`. The options can be given to `Verbatim` or any environment you define with `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` or `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment`.

You might do in your preamble

```
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{}
```

and `verbatim` will behave exactly as `Verbatim`.

You might also take advantage of this features and do

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbatimBreak}{Verbatim}{
  breaklines=true, breakanywhere=true
}
```

so you can do

```
\begin{VerbatimBreak}
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
\end{VerbatimBreak}
```

in the document for those verbatim parts that need line breaks.

Or you can do

```
\fvsetup{breaklines=true,breakanywhere=true}
```

and *all* `fancyvrb` environments will allow line breaks anywhere.